# Why Oracle weblogic server logs does not show DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE outputs?

Tags: plsql, weblogic, dbms-output

I have included some DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE inside my PLSQL package procedure. I wanted print these output in weblogic application server logs. But it does not show my DBMS_OUTPUT in weblogic server log. Currently, I use Log4j for server logging. Is there any extra configuration needed for this ? Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with Weblogic or Oracle Fusion Middleware etc, but it is likely that it does not provide any means to call `dbms_output.enable()` before each called statement and `dbms_output.get_lines()` after, and loop through the retrieved values saving them to the log. You might be able to do that in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Did you `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`? Without it, `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` won't display anything.

This is what you have:

```
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line('Hello, this is me!');
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

When output is enabled:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line('Hello, this is me!');
  3  end;
  4  /
Hello, this is me!

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what "weblogic application server" is but it's possible that it doesn't support the same `set` syntax as SQL\*Plus and SQL Developer.